How to correctly calculate Poisson's equation for electric potential using FFT with zero-padding?
I'm working on a program that simulates the electrostatic field in 3D using FFT to solve Poisson's equations based on the following formulas:
$$
\phi_{(k)} = \frac{\rho_{(k)}}{\epsilon_0 \times K^2}
$$
$$
K^2 = k^2_x\left\lvert\frac{sin(\Delta x \times k_x / 2)}{\Delta x \times k_x / 2}\right\rvert^2 + k^2_y\left\lvert\frac{sin(\Delta y \times k_y / 2)}{\Delta y \times k_y / 2}\right\rvert^2 + k^2_z\left\lvert\frac{sin(\Delta z \times k_z / 2)}{\Delta z \times k_z / 2}\right\rvert^2
$$
$$
k = \frac{2 \pi n}{L}
$$
where
$n=0,...,\frac{n}{2};-\frac{n}{2}+1,...,-1$ if $n$ is even, and
$n=0,...,\frac{n-1}{2};-\frac{n-1}{2},...,-1$ if $n$ is odd. Boundary conditions are periodic.
It works well when the number of grid nodes in each dimension is a power of two. Now, I would like to calculate the field for grids with any number of nodes in each dimension. To do this, I added zero-padding to extend the grid with zeros to the nearest power of two. Then, when calculating $k$, I use $n$ and $L$ according to the extended array. After computing potential, I use invert FFT on it, and then trim the grid to the original dimensions.
However, the simulation does not run correctly -- I test it on the example of two-stream instability and compare it with solving using Gauss-Seidel, and it is evident that the simulation is distorted:
solving with Gauss-Seidel
solving with FFT
What could be the cause of this? Should I correct the calculation of potentials after applying FFT to the charge distribution?
I also wonder what should I do when $k = 0$. At the moment while calculating $K^2$ when one of $k_x$, $k_y$ or $k_z$ equals $0$ I'm just excluding it from the sum. If $K^2 = 0$ I set the potential to $0$. Is that correct?
Code in Julia ($NX$, $NY$, $NZ$ are numbers of grid nodes in each dimension):
ρ = zeros(Float64, NX, NY, NZ) 
K2 = compute_K2(get_zero_padding_size()...)
ρ̂ = zeros(ComplexF64, get_zero_padding_size())
ϕ̂ = similar(ρ̂)
     
    function compute_K2(nx,ny,nz)
        K2 = zeros(Float64, nx,ny,nz)
    
        if nx % 2 == 0
            kx = [0:nx÷2; -nx÷2+1:-1] .* 2π ./ ((nx-1)*Δx)
        else
            kx = [0:(nx-1)÷2; -(nx-1)÷2:-1] .* 2π ./ ((nx-1)*Δx)
        end
    
        if ny % 2 == 0
            ky = [0:ny÷2; -ny÷2+1:-1] .* 2π ./ ((ny-1)*Δy)
        else
            ky = [0:(ny-1)÷2; -(ny-1)÷2:-1] .* 2π ./ ((ny-1)*Δy)
        end
    
        if nz % 2 == 0
            kz = [0:nz÷2; -nz÷2+1:-1] .* 2π ./ ((nz-1)*Δz)
        else
            kz = [0:(nz-1)÷2; -(nz-1)÷2:-1] .* 2π ./ ((nz-1)*Δz)
        end
    
        for k in 1:nz, j in 1:ny, i in 1:nx
            if kx[i] != 0
                K2[i,j,k] += kx[i]^2*((sin(Δx*kx[i]/2))/(Δx*kx[i]/2))^2
            end
            if ky[j] != 0
                K2[i,j,k] += ky[j]^2*((sin(Δy*ky[j]/2))/(Δy*ky[j]/2))^2
            end
            if kz[k] != 0
                K2[i,j,k] += kz[k]^2*((sin(Δz*kz[k]/2))/(Δz*kz[k]/2))^2
            end
        end
    
        return K2
    end

function get_zero_padding_size()
    return (ispow2(NX) ? NX : nextpow(2, NX),
            ispow2(NY) ? NY : nextpow(2, NY),
            ispow2(NZ) ? NZ : nextpow(2, NZ))
end


function bit_reversal_permutation!(x, dim)
    N = size(x, dim)
    j = 1
    for i in 1:N
        if j > i
            if dim == 1
                temp       = x[i, :, :]
                x[i, :, :] = x[j, :, :]
                x[j, :, :] = temp
            elseif dim == 2
                temp       = x[:, i, :]
                x[:, i, :] = x[:, j, :]
                x[:, j, :] = temp
            elseif dim == 3
                temp       = x[:, :, i]
                x[:, :, i] = x[:, :, j]
                x[:, :, j] = temp
            end
        end
        m = N >> 1
        while m >= 1 && j > m
            j -= m
            m >>= 1
        end
        j += m
    end
end

function fft1d_dim!(x, dim, isign)
    
    N = size(x, dim)

    step = 2
    while step <= N
        half_step = step ÷ 2
        w_m = exp(-2im* isign * π / step)

        if dim == 1
            for k in 1:step:N, l in 1:size(x, 2), m in 1:size(x, 3)
                w = 1.0
                for n in 0:(half_step-1)
                    u = x[k + n, l, m]
                    t = w * x[k + n + half_step, l, m]
                    x[k + n, l, m] = u + t
                    x[k + n + half_step, l, m] = u - t
                    w *= w_m
                end
            end
        elseif dim == 2
            for k in 1:size(x, 1), l in 1:step:N, m in 1:size(x, 3)
                w = 1.0
                for n in 0:(half_step-1)
                    u = x[k, l + n, m]
                    t = w * x[k, l + n + half_step, m]
                    x[k, l + n, m] = u + t
                    x[k, l + n + half_step, m] = u - t
                    w *= w_m
                end
            end
        elseif dim == 3
            for k in 1:size(x, 1), l in 1:size(x, 2), m in 1:step:N
                w = 1.0
                for n in 0:(half_step-1)
                    u = x[k, l, m + n]
                    t = w * x[k, l, m + n + half_step]
                    x[k, l, m + n] = u + t
                    x[k, l, m + n + half_step] = u - t
                    w *= w_m
                end
            end
        end

        step *= 2
    end

    if isign == -1
        x .= x ./ N
    end
    
    return x
end

function fft3d(x, isign)
    ρfft = zeros(ComplexF64, get_zero_padding_size())
    ρfft[1:size(x, 1), 1:size(x, 2), 1:size(x, 3)] .= convert(Array{ComplexF64, 3}, x)

    for dim in 1:3
        bit_reversal_permutation!(ρfft, dim)
        fft1d_dim!(ρfft, dim, isign)
    end
    return ρfft
end


function compute_potential_FFT!()
    ρ̂ = fft3d(ρ, 1)

    for i in 1:size(ρ̂, 1), j in 1:size(ρ̂, 2), k in 1:size(ρ̂, 3)
        if K2[i,j,k] != 0
            ϕ̂[i, j, k] = ρ̂[i, j, k] / (ε_0*K2[i,j,k])
        else
            ϕ̂[i, j, k] = 0.0
        end
    end
    
    ϕ .= real.(fft3d(ϕ̂, -1)[1:NX-1, 1:NY-1, 1:NZ-1])
end


The question is understandable but I suppose that it is unlikely to receive helpful answers unless the OP shares his simulation code for inspection.

Thank you for the advice :)

The first reaction I have : the real function you give : a linear combination of squares of moduli of 'cardinal splines' ($\operatorname{sinc}(x):=\sin(a x)/x$) doesn't look to me very sound. I wouldn't have been surprized to see instead an expression $| \alpha sinc^2(...) + \beta sinc^2() + \gamma \operatorname{sinc}^2(...) |$ with a single pair of enclosing absolute values. One thing is sure : after having applied Fourier Transform FT, then IFT, you have in general still a complex function : is it the modulus of this quantity that you are looking for (or its phase) ?

I'm interested in the modulus

You mean that this formula for $K^2$ might be wrong? I came across it in this article
